# What coastal creature leaves braid-like trace that has clear landing and take off points?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology

6/29 around 8 PM EST (within 40 minutes after downpour) the depicted trace was found in swash zone at Jacob Riis Park in NY. For reference the boot size is 12.

[image: Trace on a sand with boot as a sizing reference]
[image: Trace on a sand. Close up.]